# Sum of i.i.d Negative Multinomials

Tags: maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution, integral

I have a Negative Multinomial distribution, defined as:

\begin{align}
P(k_1,...k_D | k_0, \mathbf{p}) =
\frac{\Gamma(k_0 + \sum_i k_i) }{\Gamma(\alpha)\prod_{i} k_{i}!}
p_0^{k_0}
\prod_{i=1}^D
p_i^{k_{i}}
\end{align}

I want to compute the sum over some pre-computed subset of count vectors $\mathcal{K}$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf{k} \in \mathcal{K}} P(k_1,...k_D | k_0, \mathbf{p}) =
\sum_{\mathbf{k} \in \mathcal{K}}
\frac{\Gamma(k_0 + \sum_i k_i) }{\Gamma(\alpha)\prod_{i} k_{i}!}
p_0^{k_0}
\prod_{i=1}^D
p_i^{k_{i}}
\end{align}

How can I do it?

Or maybe it can't be done analytically?

My final goal is to find the MLE estimate of $\mathbf{p}$ for that subset $\mathcal{K}$.

Any answer or reference is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think using MLE here may give you misleading conclusions.  You know that some outcome in $\mathcal{K}$ has occured and you want to compute and maximise the likelihood $L(\mathbf{p})=P(k\in\mathcal{K})$.  For example, suppose the experiment is stopped when $k_0=1$ events in the category 0 has occured and the number of events in the other categories were any
$$
k\in \mathcal{K}=\{(10,0,0,0),(0,0,0,10)\}
$$
This tells you that $\mathbf{p}$ must be either quite close to $\mathbf{p}=(1/11,10/11,0,0,0\}$ or $\mathbf{p}=(1/11,0,0,0,10/11\}$ and this will appear as two optima in $L(\mathbf p)$ close to these values.

You may be better off doing Bayesian inference, perhaps with a Dirichlet prior on $\mathbf{p}$.  The resulting posterior would then be a Dirichlet mixture with components associated with each element in $\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: Thanks Jarle. Yes, symmetric values will give symmetric optima, I see. Yet I can't (or I'm not interested in) use Bayesian priors here since I want to understand the properties of this model, that arose as by-product of another one.

Comment: Ok, I guess the likelihood may be unimodal if all elements of $\mathcal{K}$ are clustered together, in which case MLE may give reasonable results.  If so, I don't really see where the difficulty with computing the MLEs of $\mathbf{p}$ (numerically by brute force), but perhaps an analytic expression is available if $\mathcal{K}$ has a specific form?

Comment: (sorry @Jarle, I just saw your comment) Yeap, exactly, I'm hoping that in some cases (e.g.: when K contains all integer partitions of a number) it has an analytic solution.