# Is the likelihood of the sum of unimodal likelihoods also unimodal?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multimodality

Let $p$ be a probability distribution and let $\mathcal{D}_1$, $\mathcal{D}_2$ be two sets of observations.

If the likelihood of the parameter for some observations
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta; \mathcal{D}) = p(\mathcal{D} | \theta)
$$
has a single mode, is it true that if we have

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta; \mathcal{D}) = p(\mathcal{D}_1 | \theta) + p(\mathcal{D}_2 | \theta)
$$
The likelihood over the parameter $\theta$ has a single mode as well?

If not,

- Are there some conditions or probability distributions under which this is true?
- What is usually done to find the MLE?

Comment: Is your problem regarding the sum of the random variables or the sum of the likelihoods? It's not at all the same. Why would you add two likelihoods? The sum is not a likelihood. Why would you optimize the sum for θ?

Comment: The addition is due to the fact that the data might be either D_1 or D_2. Both would be consistent with the real observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of this question appears to be false -- you don't add likelihoods like this. If the two sets of observations are independent, you would *multiply* likelihoods (add log-likelihoods).

Nevertheless (assuming it made sense in some context to even consider the question), it is *not* generally the case that sums of unimodal likelihoods would be unimodal.

It's *also* not the case that sums of unimodal *log*-likelihoods would be unimodal (e.g. consider the Cauchy which is often a counterexample).

Comment: Thanks Glen. In my context, it makes sense because it is like ignoring the real value of the observation. Then the wanted MLE is the one that maximizes the likelihood on this union set of possible values (not all possible values in the space, but the subset which is consistent with some other observation)

Comment: However, it makes sense when you switch to log-likelihoods. Which extremes are the same as the corresponding likelihoods.

Comment: @Xi'an Given the original question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265980/integral-of-a-negative-multinomial-in-a-subset-space, adding _pmf's_ (not really likelihoods) makes sense and may lead to a multimodal likelihood/posterior distribution

Answer (score 6):

Take the sum of two variance one normals, centred at $\bar{x}_1=0$ and $\bar{x}_2=4$. Then you get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: And therefore you find the MLE parameter by some optimization method? (assuming we cannot derivate it analytically)

Comment: In this extreme case, there are two equivalent MLEs. In general, you do find the MLE by an optimisation method so I am unsure about the question. MLEs exist even with multimodal likelihoods.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an. The thing is that I have a very long sum of probabilities (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265980/integral-of-a-negative-multinomial-in-a-subset-space) and I wanted to be sure that I'm not missing something trivial.

Comment: Sums are not ideal objects to optimise, but they come fairly naturally in statistics.